# Angularjs form data not storing in database

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to store form data into database through angularjs but it is not storing into the database. Don't know what I am doing wrong?

My html form

```
<form  id="challenge_form" class="row" >
            <input type="text" placeholder="Challenge Name" ng-model="challengeName" />
            <select class="btn-group form-control" id="sel1" ng-model="challengeType">
                <option>-- Select Activity Type --</option>
                <option value="running">Running</option>
                <option value="walking">Walking</option>
                <option value="cycling">Cycling</option>
            </select>
            <input type="date" placeholder="Start Date" ng-model="startDate" />
            <input type="date" placeholder="End Date" ng-model="endDate" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-theme" ng-click="newChallenge()" value="Decide Prize">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-theme"  value="Cancel">

        </form>
```

My angularjs controller

```
app.controller("NewChallengesController", ["$http", "$scope", "authenticationSvc", function ($http, $scope, authenticationSvc) {
    //alert("hello, inside New Challenge Controller");

    var token = authenticationSvc.getUserInfo();
    var config = {
        headers: {
            'h5cAuthToken': token.accessToken,
            'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
        }

    };


    $scope.newChallenge = function () {
        var data = {
            "challengeName": $scope.challengeName,
            "selectedRewardId": "283081",
            "startDate": $scope.startDate,
            "endDate": $scope.endDate,
            "activityCategoryId": 51,
            "minParticipant": 0,
            "referredNumbers": "9876543213",
            "distance": 15.0,
            "challengeType": $scope.challengeType
        };

        $http.post("http://103.19.89.152:8080/ccp-services/userchallenge/create", data, config).then(function (response) {
            alert("challenge created successfully");
        });
    };

}]);
```

I am getting the alert "challenge created successfully" but data is not storing into the database. Any help is highly appreciated!!

Comment: Check whats happening in the server side. Also try to console the response.

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint in your service to which you are posting the data..Also check what response code its returning in the fiddler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Example , 
Please verify this request mapping `/ccp-services/userchallenge/create` model variable might be 
 in your model object name is totally different what you have created in angularjs. So please make sure the model variable name should be same name of UI model variable then only its bind the data and Process it.

Comment: Thanks @SakthiSureshAnand,